# Jinja - Indentation in a recursive loop with dictionary

Tags: python, templates, jinja2

I'm trying to write a template using ninja. But I can't display the right indentation! I tried a lot of stuffs but I couldn't get the expected result.
I have a dictionary like this:

```
videoNode = {'type': "VideoLoader",
            'config': {'type': "url",
                       'source': "blabla",
                       'frameBufferSize': 50,
                      }
            }
```

I would like to display something like that

```
queueVideo1:
    type: VideoLoader
    config:
        source: blabla
        type: url
        frameBufferSize: 50
```

but all I can get is:

```
queueVideo1:
    type: VideoLoader
config:
   source: blabla
type: url
frameBufferSize: 50
```

Here is my file:

```
{%- for key, value in videoNodes.iteritems() recursive -%}
    {%+ if value is mapping -%}
        {{ key }}:
        {{ loop(value.iteritems()) }}
    {%- else -%}
       {{ key }}: {{value}}
    {% endif %}
{%- endfor -%}
```

Answer (score 5):

You must try using indent function and asign a value depends of your level of indentation:

```
{{ key|indent(2, true) }}
```

You can see [the documentation here](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#indent)

Answer (score 4):

I found it helpful to use multiple indent filters to keep my yaml file indentation clear. It was getting a little confusing otherwise:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ name }}
  namespace: {{ namespace }}
data:
{% filter indent(2) %}
customResourceDefinitions: |-
  {% filter indent(2) %}
    {%- for crd in crds -%}
    - {{ crd.content|indent(2) }}
    {%- endfor -%}
  {% endfilter %}
```